# What is the meaning of this Atharva Veda hymn on bottle-gourd, drums and camel?

Tags: vedas, goddess, atharva-veda

**[Atharva Veda Book 20](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/av/av20132.htm)** has this curious hymn that I couldn't make sense of:

> Then too the single **bottle-gourd**, the bottle-gourd dug
>      from the earth,
>
> The lute dug up from out the ground: this the wind stirs
>      and agitates.
>
> Let him prepare a nest, they say: he shall obtain it strong
>      and stretched.
>
> He shall not gain it unspread out. Who among these will
>      touch the lute?
>
> Who among these will beat the drum? How, if he beat it,
>      will he beat?
>
> **Where beating will the Goddess beat again again about the
>      house?**
>
> Three are the names the **camel** bears, Golden is one of them,
>      he said.
>
> Glory and power, these are two. He with black tufts of hair
>      shall strike.

**Does any scriptural commentary give the meaning of this verse especially the bit about the goddess and the camel?**

Comment: I think the  bottle-gourd mentioning is a analogy to show how a king has to be or he should behave. The commentaries also not helping  much , but one commentator is explaining the inner meaning (which is not confirmed by others) will try to answer , need to read  this and adjacent suktas   thoroughly  in order to know in which context this example is used. But griffith translation is not that accurate as compared to others.

Comment: Yes the only thing I could make out from this is that perhaps the bottle gourd is dug up to be used as a lute and then used with drums but on the whole it is not making much sense to me.

Comment: Ok , as i said these are used just as examples like ,  how  bottle-gourd although even emptied from inside can be used to carry water , or can create beautiful sound if used to make veena. So this is more like advice to a king etc. They are not directly related to something .